# JProgressbar not appearing in Frame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe

I am calling another thread from main class. In that thread i wanted to show JProgressBar with indeterminate mode But When i call For The class the empty frame appears and not showing progressbar

The thread code is here

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class Verify extends JFrame implements Runnable 
{

    JProgressBar bar;


   public Verify(long ID,String path) 
    {


    }
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        bar =new JProgressBar();
        bar.setIndeterminate(true);
        bar.setStringPainted(true);
        bar.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(bar);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //Do some work here

        if(flag==true)
        {
            //call for another thread         
            frame.dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }




}
```

and call from this thread fro main class is here

```
private void Process_ContactActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String Id=Id_Field.getText().toString().trim();

    if(Id.isEmpty())
    {
        //job

    }
    else
    {

        if(path==null)
        {
           //Job 
        }
        else
        {
            long id=Long.parseLong(Id);
            Verify verify=new Verify(id,path);
            verify.run();


        }
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your code

```
 long id=Long.parseLong(Contact_Id);
 Verify verify=new Verify(id,path);
 new Thread(verify).start();
```

We don't see any `Verify_Contact` class or references anywhere. Adding to that, Verify is a `Runnable` Object. so, you need to give it to a `Thread` instance to execute it. You should use `start()` method instead of invoking the `run()` method directly

Answer (score 2):

Your class is called `Verify` but your so-called constructor is called `Verify_Contact`. I could see that causing a problem.

- **Also**, your class is already a `JFrame`. No need to create another `JFrame`. just add the progress bar to the class `JFrame`

So in your `run()` just do this

```
    add(bar);

    pack();
    // setSize(300, 300);   <--- why pack AND setSize?  
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
```

And in your constructor

```
    public Verify(long ID,String path) 
    {
        Local_cid=ID;
        local_path=path;
        // frame=new JFrame("Processing Contact"); <-- leave this out
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    }
```

- Also, I don't see these `Local_cid`, `local_path` as fields in the class, yet you're trying to access them in your constructor. Maybe  you just left it out of your code, who knows.

---

- **Also** , post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help.

Comment: Nice catch, How doesn't it create any compilation problem?

Comment: @Octopus not sure. I'm hoping this is a Typo by the OP

Comment: My mistake i left the part and commented part also included that's why it is creating confusion